# Why we make Node class and LinkedList class instead of doing it simple way like

Tags: python, data-structures

i have just started learning data structures and algorithms and i want to know why do we make node and linkedlist classes separately rather doing everything in a single class like i did

```
class LinkedList():              
    def __init__(self):
        self.linked=[]

    def add(self,data):
        self.linked.append(data)
        return self.linked

    def get_size(self):
        return len(self.linked)

    def remove(self,data):
        if data in self.linked:
            while data in self.linked:
                z=self.linked.index(data)
                del self.linked[z]
                print self.linked
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def find(self,data):
        if data in self.linked:
            return "Found" + " " + str(data)
        else:
            return "Not found" + " " + str(data)
```

Is that because of space and time complexity or some other factors?
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linked list means that each element has a pointer (= link) to the next element in the list. A typical `Node` class stores that pointer. Your `LinkedList` class is just a wrapper for a standard Python list, not a linked list.

Comment: Thanks Robin,but with little modifications i can write new methods to return next element and previous element of any node.Does it a bad coding practice for linked list or its also acceptable?

Comment: @Sam1313 It’s not about the methods your list provides, it is about the way it stores its data. The concept of a linked list is to store one item with a pointer to the next one. The default Python lists – that you use to store the data – are arrays. That means they basically store one element after the other in continuous memory. These are two genuinely different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement Linked list with traditional approach of c type structure using

```
class Node:
    def __init__():
        self.val = val
        self.next = None
```

type of definition. and using this class in Main Linked list class

```
class LinkedList( Node):
```